# How to sort this outer join of three tables that won't work?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a list of classes and a list of users in two mySQL tables.
As it is a multiple relation between both tables, I do have a third table that allows me to relate several users to several courses and vice versa.

The structure is (all not null values):

**classes table**

```
classID
```

**users table**

```
userID
enrollementDate
```

**classesUsers table**

```
classID
userID
```

Now, I want to show a list of all available classes and inside that list show the classes where the user X is enrolled.

I can't do that. Either I do show all the classes or all the classes where the user id 10 is enrolled.

**The desired output is:**

```
ClassID -------- enrollementDate
Class 1 -------- 10-10-2010
Class 2     
Class 3 -------- 05-05-2015
Class 4     
Class 5 -------- 15-02-2016
```

I'm trying this and I do get the whole list:

```
SELECT 
classes.classID,
users.enrollementDate

FROM classes
LEFT OUTER JOIN classesUsers
ON classes.classID = classesUsers.classID

LEFT JOIN users
ON classesUsers.userID = users.userID

GROUP BY classes.classID
```

If I want to add the specific user, I get just the list of that user's enrolled classes:

```
SELECT 
classes.classID,
users.enrollementDate

FROM classes
LEFT OUTER JOIN classesUsers
ON classes.classID = classesUsers.classID

LEFT JOIN users
ON classesUsers.userID = users.userID

WHERE users.userID = 10
GROUP BY classes.classID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your exact desired output.

Comment: Why does your `users` table have an enrollment date?  The enrollment date should be associated with a given class _and_ user, not just a user, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `LEFT JOIN`, you have to put restrictions on the child table in the `ON` clause. Otherwise, you'll filter out all the non-matching rows, because they'll have `NULL` in the `users.userID` column, and that will not match `WHERE users.userID = 10`.

```
SELECT 
    classes.classID,
    classesUsers.userID,
    users.enrollementDate
FROM classes
LEFT OUTER JOIN classesUsers ON classes.classID = classesUsers.classID AND classesUsers.userID = 10
LEFT JOIN users ON classesUsers.userID = users.userID
```

There's no need for `GROUP BY`, since each class will only appear once: either with a single `NULL` row if there's no match, or with the one matching row in `classesUsers`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I'm reading answer upon answer about different type of JOINS, and I'm reading Paul DuBois' MySQL book and still didn't understand the concept. Thank you for the explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

Move the check for user from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t1.classID,
       t2.userID,
       t3.enrollementDate
FROM classes t1
LEFT JOIN classesUsers t2
    ON t1.classID = t2.classID
LEFT JOIN users t3
    ON t2.userID = t3.userID AND
       t3.userID = 10
```

The check in your `WHERE` clause was completely removing non matching records.  But you want all records to appear in your result set, though some might be empty.